# Possible bug? Parent object (empty) moves along child (camera) when using Walk Mode

Tags: camera, parent

I'm not sure if to report this as a bug for it might be me just not properly understanding a basic feature.

So I setup a camera and an empty, parent the camera to that empty (so I can freely move and rotate the camera without affecting the empty), and it works just fine.

BUT if I then enter into walk mode to adjust the camera, the parent object in this case the empty, moves along with the camera, behaving as if it was a child?

Any idea, am I missing something?